# Set dropdown list from server value on dynamic created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with setting value of dropdown list in dynamic created `div` with edit form.

```
document.getElementById("edit-entry").innerHTML = "";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'edit';
div.innerHTML =  "form html";
document.getElementById('edit-entry').appendChild(div);
```

in `html` it is

```
<div id="edit-entry"></div>
```

on console it's working `("#sel-change-app").val("9");` But when i try to get it under `appendChild`, or with `$(function() { }` still no change. How to check if `div` is ready for setting values? As i debug i see that sel-change-app is slower than div, couse list is from server.

Comment: Why don't you do it after `document.getElementById('edit-entry').appendChild(div);`? - Another choice is to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: add up a fiddle to understand better.

Comment: just right the below code after your appendChild statement: 
jQuery('#edit-entry div').text(jQuery("#sel-change-app").val());

Comment: couse its not working. I tried, i think its couse sel-change-app is from function, so its not ready when i set value.

Comment: document.getElementById('edit-entry').appendChild(div);jQuery('#edit-entry div').text(jQuery("#sel-change-app").val("7")); return [object Object] form is not showing

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select#sel').find('option').each(function() {
            var t=$(this).val();
            $("#mySelect").append(t+"<br>");
        });
    }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="sel" name="sel">
        <option value="o1">1</option>
        <option value="o2">1</option>
        <option value="o3">1</option>
        <option value="o4">1</option>
    </select>
    <div id="mySelect"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's harder, couse as i write, list is getting from server, so i need to wait till it gets i think i need to use callback :/